# multiplie outputs with different wheres

Tags: sql

What do I have to change to get different results from different names.The table should give me the debts of each of them, this is calculated by the amount and the price of the drink. Now it should show all the names with the corresponding invoice that happens after the select

```
%sql  select name, sum(getraenk.preis*schulden.menge) schulden from schulden \
join person on (fk_person = person.id)\
join getraenk on (fk_getraenk = getraenk.id)\
where name like ("dani")
```

[image: s]

Edit: it should spend all the names with their debts, that is:
 dani = 8.5
michael = 12.5
...

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: This query is probably doing it correctly already -- what is wrong when you remove the where clause how is it not different by name as you expect?

Comment: it gives me all the individual names with the debts, but I would like to sum up all debts of each person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case your problem is very simple, you should be able to see all names and values with an SQL that looks like this:

```
select name, getraenk.preis*schulden.menge schulden 
from schulden 
join person on (fk_person = person.id)
join getraenk on (fk_getraenk = getraenk.id)
```

Note that I removed the where clause... this was the part that limited it to one name.

You also don't need the sum clause here unless you are doing a group by

Comment: it gives me all the individual names with the debts, but I would like to sum up all debts of each person

Comment: @euli then add a group by

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using `GROUP BY name` at the end of this query?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

This will give you the sum of total debt for all names in your table which sounds like the result you are looking for.

Comment: w3schools is generally considered a bad place to send people for help.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing

```
GROUP BY name
```

in the query.